# Ajax response removing trailing zeros on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently using ajax to make a call to a web api. When I get a response back in the IE Network monitor, I view the response body and I see my variable with trailing zeros in the Json.

```
"Blah" : 50.50000
```

But when I display the output of the ajax call I that value is now 50.5

How is this possible?

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:jsonData,
    async:false,
    url:urlConfig,
    contentType:"application/json",
    success:function(response) {doTasks(response);});

 function doTasks(data){
     document.getElementById('test').value = JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
 }
```

While debugging I see that the trailing zeros are gone before the stringify method is called.

Comment: It’s `"application/json"`, not `"application\json"`.

Comment: The DECIMAL field is converted to a JSON NUMBER data type.
This type trims trailing zeros by default.

Comment: @Santi is there a way to keep the zeros

Comment: You could return it as a string instead of a number and then parse it as you need, or just add the zeros back.

Comment: Use the `toFixed` method.

Comment: Its possible that the number of trailing zeros will be different, sometimes it will be one sometimes two. I want to keep the exact number of zeros the same without specifying a default format for every number.

Comment: Then you have to return it as a string instead of a number: `"50.50000"`

Comment: @TylerRoper isn't there a need for JSON NUMBER to convert 50.50000 as it is instead of using string ?